How to obtain detailed information about errors
I got this error: Function .... compiled with errors. Compile the function in the editor to obtain detailed information.
How I can solve this ? I have spent all my ideas yet.
Thanks so much.
Best regards
I tried all advices from the internet.

can you post a screenshot?
